# No se detecta un bucle del código

Tags: c

Resulta que en un programa que imprima todas las posibles combinaciones de dos dígitos, solo me imprime unos cuantos y el programa se deja de ejecutar.
Uso la función write pero no acabo de entender su funcionamiento.

```
Output obtenido: 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,
Output deseado: 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15...
```

Adjunto el código

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_print_comb2(void)
{
    char a;
    char b;

    a = b = '0';
    while (a <= '9')
    {
        while (b <= '9')
        {
            write(1, &a, 1);
            write(1, &b, 1);
            write(1, ", ", 1);
            ++b;
        }
        ++a;
    }
}

int main() {
    ft_print_comb2();
}
```

Comment: `write` es una función de Linux que llama directamente al sistema. ¿No te parece incómodo tener que pasar 3 parámetros? Bueno, podrías crear una función que lo simplifique, usando [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen). Puedes crear tu propia implementación si prefieres (no es muy difícil). O también puedes usar [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) que es más flexible.

Comment: Es un error, al no reiniciar la variable b a '0' otra vez dentro del primer bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el bucle interno se ha ejecutado todas las veces (y ha salido por pantalla la secuencia `01, 02, 03, ..., 09`, se abandona el bucle interno, y se vuelve al bucle externo. Al salir de ese bucle `b` vale `':'` pues ese es el ASCII que va después del `'9'`

Entonces se incrementa `a` que pasa a valer `'1'` y se vuelve a iterar el bucle externo. Pero al llegar al `while` interno, como `b` todavía vale `':'` la condición del while interno no se cumple, por lo que no se ejecuta (y por tanto no se imprime nada). De este modo el bucle externo se vuelve a ejecutar todas las veces y la `a` va pasando por los valores `'1'`, `'2'`, etc. pero en ninguna de esas veces se entra al bucle interno ya, por lo que todas esas iteraciones del bucle externo no producen salida.

Solución: inicializa `b` con `'0'` dentro del bucle externo:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_print_comb2(void)
{
    char a;
    char b;

    a = b = '0';
    while (a <= '9')
    {
        b = '0';
        while (b <= '9')
        {
            write(1, &a, 1);
            write(1, &b, 1);
            write(1, ", ", 1);
            ++b;
        }
        ++a;
    }
}

int main() {
    ft_print_comb2();
}
```

Salida:

```
00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,
46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,
69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,
92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,
```

Comment: Estaría bien, saber si hay algún truco para eliminar esa coma final en la salida

Comment: @Francisco Cambia el tercer write por `if (a!='9' || b!='9') write(1, ", ", 1);`